# Paypal GetExpressCheckoutDetails missing PAYERID

Tags: paypal

( see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/ )

1. We log the user in via OpenID (Log In With PayPal) and receive an access token.
2. We call SetExpressCheckout giving the IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN
3. We call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and expect the PAYERID to be populated. It does not exist in the response.

I cannot call DoExpressCheckoutPayment without having the PAYERID.

I have attached the request/response data below.
Notice that GetExpressCheckoutDetails does not contain PAYERID.
Why might this be happening?

Thanks!

```
SetExpressCheckout Request:
array (size=23)
  'METHOD' => string 'SetExpressCheckout' (length=18)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  'RETURNURL' => string 'https://some.url/' (length=39)
  'CANCELURL' => string 'https://some.url/' (length=25)
  'VERSION' => string '106.0' (length=5)
  'USER' => string 'secure-paypal_api1.somedomain.com' (length=30)
  'PWD' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=16)
  'SIGNATURE' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=56)
  'NOSHIPPING' => string '1' (length=1)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => string 'Sale' (length=4)
  'HDRIMG' => string 'https://www.some.url/.jpg' (length=70)
  'EMAIL' => string 'foo@foo.com' (length=23)
  'CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER' => string '1-111-111-1111' (length=14)
  'ALLOWNOTE' => string '0' (length=1)
  'IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN' => string '2nd3CS9HG1EWzTQGy6l.4n7CsilVWgkqn20bTuUfSXX' (length=43)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => string 'or3333' (length=6)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => string 'Product name foobar' (length=31)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => string '1' (length=1)

SetExpressCheckout Response:
array (size=6)
  'TOKEN' => string 'EC-4W147554UR614711B' (length=20)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2014-01-17T20:41:50Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string '4ef48694990' (length=11)
  'ACK' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '106.0' (length=5)
  'BUILD' => string '9285531' (length=7)

GetExpressCheckoutDetails Request:
array (size=6)
  'METHOD' => string 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails' (length=25)
  'TOKEN' => string 'EC-4W147554UR614711B' (length=20)
  'VERSION' => string '106.0' (length=5)
  'USER' => string 'secure-paypal_api1.sylvane.com' (length=30)
  'PWD' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=16)
  'SIGNATURE' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=56)

GetExpressCheckoutDetails Response:
array (size=44)
  'TOKEN' => string 'EC-4W147554UR614711B' (length=20)
  'CHECKOUTSTATUS' => string 'PaymentActionNotInitiated' (length=25)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2014-01-17T20:41:50Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string '605766387f780' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '106.0' (length=5)
  'BUILD' => string '9285531' (length=7)
  'CURRENCYCODE' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  'AMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'ITEMAMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'SHIPPINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'HANDLINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'TAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'INSURANCEAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'SHIPDISCAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'L_NAME0' => string 'or2395' (length=6)
  'L_QTY0' => string '1' (length=1)
  'L_TAXAMT0' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'L_AMT0' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'L_DESC0' => string 'Product name foobar' (length=31)
  'L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED' => string 'false' (length=5)
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS' => string 'None' (length=4)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => string 'or3333' (length=6)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => string '1' (length=1)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => string '329.00' (length=6)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => string 'Product name foobar' (length=31)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0' => string '   0.00000' (length=10)
  'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you pass the `IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN` in the SetExpressCheckout call, you still need to redirect the buyer over to PayPal so that they can approve the payment.  Setting `IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN` allows the buyer to skip the login page, making the process quicker for them, but they still need to go over to PayPal to approve the payment.  After you make your SetExpressCheckout call, redirect them to `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token={token}` (where `{token}` is the value of `TOKEN` from the SetExpressCheckout response).